# Keep selected menu active after postback

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

How do I keep the menu selected stay active even after postback? Below are coding that I currently use.

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu-promo">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu-promo {background-color: #ff9100; display: inline-block; font-family: Calibri; width: 100%; padding: 45px 20px 20px 20px; border: 1px 0px 0px 0px solid #b3e5fc; font-weight: bold; color: #fff!important;}
#menu-promo ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; display: block;}
#menu-promo ul > li {list-style: none; display: inline-block;}
#menu-promo ul > li a {color: #fff; border: 2px solid #ff9100; border-radius: 20px; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; text-decoration: none;}
#menu-promo ul > li a:hover {background-color: #eeeeee; border: 2px solid #01579b; cursor: pointer; color: #01579b; text-decoration: none;}
#menu-promo ul li a.active {background-color: #eeeeee; border: 2px solid #01579b; cursor: pointer; color: #01579b; text-decoration: none;}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    var selector = '#menu-promo ul li a';

    $(selector).on('click', function () {
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to register a startup script in every `page_load` event in your code behind to call a JavaScript function.

This function requires you set id's for each menu item and pass that id eg. `#menuItemID`

```
function setActive(menuItemID){
    var selector = '#menu-promo ul li ' + menuItemID;
    $(selector).addClass('active');
}
```

**C# & VB.Net**  (Might be `[GetType]()` for VB)

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:setActive(thisMenuItemID); ", true);
```

If your menu items' text match your page names correctly you could use a function like

```
function setActive(){
    // Might need to play with substring parameters
    var selector = '#menu-promo ul li a[name=' + location.pathname.substring(0, location.pathname.indexOf(".")) + ']';
    $(selector).addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this in master page

     $(document).ready(function () {
          var page= document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
          var limenu = $('.sidebar-menu li');
          $.each(limenu, function (index, value) {
              if ($(value).find('a').attr('href') != (page+'.aspx')) {
                    $(value).removeClass('active');                      
              } else {
                  if (!$(value).hasClass('active')) {
                       $(value).addClass('active');
                  }                   
              }
          });          
      });
```